# Synthesis: Implementing a delay signal using a counter on power-up of FPGA

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am trying to have a delay of 20 seconds on power-up of the FPGA.

There is a clock input of 100Hz, so if a counter gets to 20,000, that should be 20 seconds worth of delay.  After the delay, it should set an output pin high.  However, for some reason, this out pin is going high immediately and never goes low at all on powerup.  It's almost as if it is skipping the s_count <= 20000 completely.

Here is the code I have:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity delay is
port 
(
    pi_Clock      : in std_logic;
    po_Delay_Done : out std_logic
);
end entity;
architecture behavioral of delay is
begin
    process(pi_Clock)
        variable s_count : integer := 0;
    begin
        if rising_edge(pi_Clock) then
            if s_count <= 20000 then           
                s_count := s_count + 1;
                po_Delay_Done <= '0';
            else
                po_Delay_Done <= '1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

I have increased the 20000 to the max integer value, just to see if my clock was incorrect but the same result.

There is no other driver of this signal on the top level file.

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: 20,000 @ 100Hz = 200s, not 20s. You could also try toggling every N cycles (vary as needed) just to see if you can generate any activity on that output at all.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing that out.
I have confirmed I can toggle it with the clock cycle, therefore that variable must be incrementing correctly.  Perhaps the synthesis is incorrectly optimizing out my signal assignment since the count is never reset to zero?

Comment: Have you tried this in simulation yet? Going directly to synthesis might have issues with pin mapping. Some other things to try: set a default value to the output to set the initial state, add a reset (even if you don't use it), ensure that your pi_Clock isn't behaving erratically (high frequency input spikes) upon power up.

Comment: Also, mention which synth tool and FPGA this is. It is still possible that some tools don't support initial values on variables, and expect a traditional reset.

Comment: I have not tried this yet in simulation.  I am embarrassed to say I haven't figured out how to use the sim yet with this toolset and I have just been using a scope to look at output pins.  The synth tool is synopsis Synplify and the FPGA is Actel A3PN250.  I will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, setting the initial values by the declarations seems to be the problem with this FPGA/toolset (synopsis Synplify and the FPGA is Actel A3PN250) even if it works in modelsim simulation.

The following code does what I want -- Set an output high after the FPGA is turned on for 20 seconds:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity delay is
port 
(
    pi_Clock      : in std_logic;
    pi_Reset      : in std_logic;
    po_Delay_Done : out std_logic
);
end entity;

architecture behavioral of delay is

begin

    process(pi_Clock)
        variable s_count: integer;
    begin
        if rising_edge(pi_Clock) then
            if pi_Reset = '1' then
                s_count := 0;
                po_Delay_Done <= '0';
            else            
                if s_count < 2000 then           
                    s_count := s_count + 1;             
                else
                    po_Delay_Done <= '1';                   
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;      
    end process;    
end architecture;
```

The catch is that the microcontroller is now sending a reset signal (pi_Reset = '1') to the FPGA after it has been started.

Hope this helps anyone in the future, thanks to Quantum Ripple and Brian especially for suggesting the hard reset.  If you had an answer I would accept it.

Comment: Synplicity (Actel/Microsemi Libero 9 edition) definitely has some "features" and would have been my guess. (Not jumping horses mid-project means I haven't tried Libero 11). Having done the work, it's perfectly OK to accept your own answer. Also, sim would have given the confidence much faster. (Modelsim can be a little daunting, if you don't want to learn it, there are alternatives, like ghdl+gtkwave. http://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/?source=navbar

Answer (score 0):

The code you typed has no simulation or synthesis errors and has a correct result in modelsim simulation software. (according to the above first comment "fru1tbat")

With respect to the above comments, I think if you synthesized the FPGA board correctly and the design doesn't worked (with applying a reset port to reset the output and variable parameters), the problem is related to the clock generator. Be sure about the clock generator and find the correct frequency.